# Microsoft Office Packages

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

Is there anyway to find out what each Microsoft package has installed?

What im after is any Microsoft Office package which comes with powerpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info for office 2007 is here - [office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/products/FX101635841033.aspx)

The basic 3, which includes Powerpoint (along with Word and Excel) comes with all editions of office 2007 - Home & Student, Standard, Small Business, Professional and Ultimate.

Comment: I am also talking Microsoft basic 2003 etc older versions as well

Answer (score 1):

Office 2003 comes in 4 editions. Standard, Small Business, Student & Teacher and Professional.

All come with Word, Excel, Powerpoint and Outlook.

Full details are [here](http://www.microsoft.com/products/info/compare.aspx?view=22&pcid=3c3bd1bb-5595-4512-bcca-f764770e1d71).